# correct the error in product buy sell date wise data

Tags: sas

```
DATA PRODINVENTRY;
INPUT STORE $ PRODUCT $  BUY_SELL $ DATE DDMMYY10. UNITS PRICE INVENTRY;
CARDS; 
1 pen      B 01/01/2012 2  10.00 2 
1 pen      B 04/02/2012 8  15.00 10 
1 pen      S 08/02/2012 10 15.00 0 
1 pencil   B 02/02/2012 5  5.00 5 
1 pencil   S 04/02/2012 4  7.00 1 
2 book     B 01/01/2012 5  20.00 5 
2 book     S 05/02/2012 6  30.00 -1 
2 notebook B 02/02/2012 4  15.00 4 
2 notebook S 04/02/2012 5  15.00 -1 
3 rubber   B 01/01/2012 2  5.00 2 
3 rubber   B 02/02/2012 2  5.00 4 
3 rubber   B 04/02/2012 2  5.00 6 
3 rubber   S 05/02/2012 5  5.00 1 
4 slipper  B 01/01/2012 3  150.00 3 
4 slipper  B 02/02/2012 5  200.00 8 
4 slipper  B 04/02/2012 5  100.00 13 
4 slipper  S 05/02/2012 14 90.00 -1 
5 desktop  B 02/02/2012 4  30000.00 4 
5 desktop  S 04/02/2012 3  30000.00 1 
5 desktop  S 05/02/2012 1  30000.00 0 
5 laptop   S 01/01/2012 3  20000.00 -3
5 laptop   B 08/02/2012 8  20000.00 5 
;
```

this is product buy/sell datewise data with units inventry. there is error in data.
1. sold the units more than buy.
2. sold the units before bought.
I want to remove all wrong entry or rectify the data by changing the date or units within store. Note : There can only be products sold after a product has been bought for one store.

Comment: I'd suggest that you provide some information on how you're attempting to solve this problem.  As presented it looks like a homework problem, and nobody's doing anyone a favor by simply solving it for you; and if it's not homework, you still ought to have some thoughts as to how to solve this (fairly simple) problem.  If you have more specific questions as to how certain elements of your approach might work, you'll get more useful feedback AND learn more about SAS.

Comment: I used sql to solve the problum but only i can solved the product problum, buy units are more then equal to sold units. I am new to sas, so please do me a favour.

Comment: PROC SQL NOPRINT;
CREATE TABLE ERROR AS
SELECT S.*, S.UNITS-B.UNITS AS EXTRA_SOLD 
FROM BUYINVENTRY AS B RIGHT JOIN SELLINVENTRY AS S
ON B.PRODUCT = S.PRODUCT AND B.STORE = S.STORE
HAVING B.UNITS < S.UNITS
ORDER BY STORE, PRODUCT;
QUIT;

Answer (score 0):

The SQL solution to the second part isn't terribly different from the first.  You can do it with a join, or with an exists subquery (similarly, the first part that you already solved can be solved with either); here is the exists version:

```
proc sql;
create table error as
    select * from PRODINVENTRY S
    where buy_sell='S' and not exists (
        select 1 from PRODINVENTRY B
        where B.buy_sell='B' and B.store=S.store and B.product=S.product and B.date<S.date);
quit;
```

If you wanted to do both in one step, you could have two exists subqueries easily [and (not exists (...) or not exists (...) )] or two joins.

Answer (score 0):

data SAMPLE;

set PRODINVENTRY;

FORMAT DATE DATE9.;

If INVENTRY > UNITS then INVENTRY = UNITS;

run;

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you explain it, rather than just state the solution.